# Why am I getting "TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor..." after changing my loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When I change my loss function
from

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    L1_loss = keras.mean(keras.abs(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
    ssim_loss = 1 - (tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_val=1.0, filter_size=5)))
    loss = L1_loss + 2.0 * SSIM_loss
    return loss
```

to

```
def custom_loss(deltaT1):
  def total_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    L1_loss = keras.mean(keras.abs(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
    ssim_loss = 1 - (tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_val=1.0, filter_size=5)))
    mask_loss = keras.mean(keras.abs(y_true-y_pred)*deltaT1,axis=-1)
    loss = 1.0 * L1_loss + 5.0 * ssim_loss + 1.0 * mask_loss
    return loss
  return total_loss
```

I will see this error message:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 317, in __call__
        self._total_loss_mean.update_state(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 477, in update_state  **
        sample_weight = tf.__internal__.ops.broadcast_weights(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 283, in __array__
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_5'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

And this is my model. Fit function

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=custom_loss(mask), metrics=metrics)

....

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  history = model.fit(train_img_datagen,
                      steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      verbose=1,
                      validation_data=val_img_datagen,
                      validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch,
                      callbacks=[callbacks])
```

Is this a problem caused by the version of TensorFlow? Because it went wrong after I added deltaT1, which I wrote mimicking line 41 of [this repository](https://github.com/chenchao666/Contrast-enhanced-MRI-Synthesis/blob/master/HRNet(3D)/utils.py).

Comment: Can u add a colab gist, so other can reproduce exactly? I feel like with some adjustment, it is completly doable.